# how to create react build in one folder, i don't want js and css inside static folder

Tags: reactjs, npm, build

I want to create build for a react app where i want all the components of build inside one folder, baiscally i don't want static/js or static/cs.

I tried adding postbuild scripts but that changed only the home directory.
older version of react used webpack config but the latest one doesnot.